# How can I use my iMac as a firewall for my Windows computer?

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, vpn, firewall

I have a 2011 iMac running macOS High Sierra (10.13), which I use for browsing and streaming, besides my Windows computer.

Since I don't have a 5ghz WiFi adapter on my PC, I share the iMac internet connection with my PC via cable directly from the iMac.

I already tried to share my iKev2 VPN connection from iMac to Windows, but unfortunately, there is no way to share ikev2 VPN connections with other devices.

Now I want to know if there is a way to set up a firewall in the iMac, to analyze Windows internet usage, and mainly, block a few hosts, for my PC to don't connect.

I already have a GlassWire subscription on Windows, but I want something out of the computer to block and analyze every traffic from my PC. Is it possible?

I've heard about setting a PiHole with a RaspberryPI to create a local DNS and block hosts this way, but unfortunately, I don't have a RaspBerryPI.

Comment: Please use proper formatting. Use italics and bold for emphasis - that's what they were invented for - and save code formatting for code. I've fixed this for you.

Comment: Thanks so much for using your time to edit it @gronostaj!

Comment: @gronostaj Jumping into the formatting issue, but bolding doesn’t help this — and other — questions and answers. It just seems overly aggressive when the question is very clear as is. So I removed the bolding. Utterly no need for it.

Comment: Thanks for jumping in, Mr. @Giacomo1968! Now it's even better formated, thanks to you! It feels nice to start here on superuser.com in 2021. I feel a little bit late, but I think it's always time. Hope I can contribute with other users here! Thanks!

Comment: Let's get the elephants out of the room: Why do you not want to block these hosts and analyze internet usage directly on Windows? Have you looked into setting up PiHole on Windows or iMac?

Comment: Nice that you added it @gronostaj! I'm not 100% trusting this machine anymore. I have already monitoring software on it and it is Glasswire Pro. I just came to know that PiHole can be installed on another device than RaspberryPI after asking this question. But anyway, I'm almost solving it with: https://github.com/TechnitiumSoftware/DnsServer, which seems to be the father of PiHole. I'm running it but didn't made it to connect yet. As soon as I make it work, I'll come back here to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to achieve similar results, is using the iMac as a DNS resolver for the PC.

This can be achieved with a variety of apps.

I chose [DNS Server by Technitium](https://github.com/TechnitiumSoftware/DnsServer) and [Pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/).

But with both apps, while sharing internet connection, you must kill the "mDNSResponder" process before launching your own DNS resolver, which leads to an impracticable day-to-day performance.

[You can read more on how to make DNS Server work while sharing internet connection on macOS here.](https://github.com/TechnitiumSoftware/DnsServer/issues/274)